# FusionTables Insert works in OAuth2 Playground, but not as HTTPS Post in other systems

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

Hello kind people of the internet,

We can successfully use the Google Oauth 2.0 Playground to make a simple sql POST insert to a FusionTable, but when attempt the same basic HTTPS POST operation in anything else (from back end system, another browser session, Postman chrome  tool, hurl.it, etc, etc), we always get a 403 error:

```
 "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
```

I'm puzzled why the error is returned when doing an HTTPS post from other systems (other than OAuth playground)?...as at the time I'm supplying an active Access token (cut-n-pasted Access token from OAuth playground).

The successful-working-good Request block in OAuth 2.0 Playground is below (but the Access token is of course now expired):

```
 POST /fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT INTO 1CqwRGEEn4L0gN66JwGvCR5yOI8miNMVijcp4XlE (Name, Age) VALUES ('Forrest', 57) HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.googleapis.com
 Content-type: application/json
 Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRr9CkHptvLaYlba_u6wceIh29urI8FjFp8xMP08AcBm2qpHg
```

Here's the direct URL that is generated by several different REST based tools I'm attempting to use to simulate the HTTPS request to do a POST sql insert to FusionTables (which again: always generates a 403 error even with an active Access token):

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT%20INTO%201CqwRGEEn4L0gN66JwGvCR5yOI8miNMVijcp4XlE%20(Name,%20Age)%20VALUES%20('Jim',%2057)=&Content-length:=0&Content-type:%20=application/json&Authorization:=%20Bearer%20ya29.AHES6ZRr9CkHptvLaYlba_u6wceIh29urI8FjFp8xMP08AcBm2qpHg
```

Some other notes:
-In my Google APIs Console, I'm using the "Client ID for web applications".

-I updated the FusionTable properties with the Api console email-address to allow edit capability on the fusiont table used in the above sql (1CqwRGEEn4L0gN66JwGvCR5yOI8miNMVijcp4XlE)  Adding the email for edit capability to the FusionTable properties was kindly suggested by Odi for Service accounts on another related post on FusionTables).

Any help in explaining why HTTPS Post works in the OAuth playground for a sql insert to FusionTables, but not anywhere else would surely be appreciated...there must be something I'm missing, as supposedly the OAuth playground was to help illuminate how OAuth works at a detailed level so we could handle in other systems that don't necessarily have a developed OAuth library.

Update 8/23, per the suggested answer...here's a URL syntax that works in POSTMAN and uses both the OAuth API key and an active Access token which was obtained using the OAuth playground (access token is of course fake/expired).

```
  https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=INSERT%20INTO%201CqwRGEEn4L0gN66JwGvCR5yOI8miNMVijcp4XlE%20(Name,%20Age)%20VALUES%20('Bob',%2031)=&Content-length:=0&Content-type:%20=application/json&key={OAuth API key}&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZST_c2CjdXeIyG8LwkprQMGGfoW45sonX0d1H51234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your API key to the POST. Even though the message refers to authentication I'm pretty sure it's not OAuth authentication but your API usage that needs to be verified.

Comment: Hi, Where in the syntax does the Api key get included?...how is it declared?...would you have an example?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer...it turns out this apparently does the trick...Kathryn Hurley had another post that also hinted at the exact syntax.

Comment: Here's the link to Kathryn Hurley's discussion regrading two different syntax structures for passing the Access Token:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576733/invalid-credentials-error-when-passing-oauth-2-0-access-token-to-fusion-tables-a/9590627#9590627