# 403 Forbidden while Insert into fusion table

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I was trying to insert data into fusion table using Fusion Table API V1. And the code that I am using is

```
<?php
session_start();
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query";
$Query = "INSERT INTO 1Vzqe-X-jEcU-YpOuZTtjW0xrVZfxZA44lsxPjPU (name, phone) VALUES ('Check', '2001')";
$postQuery = http_build_query(array('sql' => $Query));
$Headers = array('Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$_SESSION['access_token'], 'Content-type' => 'application/json');
$postHeaders = http_build_query($Headers);
$context =array("http"=>
        array(
            "method" => "POST",
            "content" => $postQuery,        
            "header" => $postHeaders
            ));         
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$ResultArray = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

But it comes with 403 Forbidden.
I tried giving edit access on fusion table  to the 10781---8@developer.gserviceaccount.com -- Not working. **I can access fusion table and print its contents, issue is on write access on to fusion table.**

**Note-> CURL is not allowed, I am on Google app engine.**

Comment: a search sometimes can help to find an example how to do it... see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/20430381/1545993

Comment: Answer for this question is:   
        $post = array(
                     sql' => $Query,
              );
        $post = http_build_query($post);
        $context =array("http"=>
            array(
             "method" => "POST",
      "content" => $post, 
                "header" => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['access_token'],
          ));     
        $context = stream_context_create($context);
        $ResultArray = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            ?>

I hope this will help someone looking for a straight answer.